# Ansible include_tasks doesn't work and shows no error

Tags: automation, ansible, devops, ansible-2.x, ansible-inventory

i am applying the following structure in my ansible directory:

```
├── ansible.cfg
├── atom.yml
├── bash_aliases.yml
├── group_vars
│   ├── debian.yml
├── host_vars
├── inventory
├── nmap.yml
└── roles
    ├── debian
    │   ├── files
    │   ├── handlers
    │   └── tasks
    │       ├── add_aliases.yml
    │       ├── install_atom.yml
    │       ├── install_nmap.yml
    │       └── main.yml
```

I want to install nmap on my debian servers (which are accessible by ansible) but i get no errors and no changes applied to the servers, when i run the following command:

`ansible-playbook nmap.yml --ask-become-pass --tags nmap`

The tasks are:

1. install_nmap.yml

```
- name: install nmap
  apt:
    name: "{{ item }}"
    state: latest
  with_items: "{{ packages }}"
```

2. main.yml

```
---
- include_tasks: install_nmap.yml
  tags: [ 'nmap' ]
  when: true
```

group_vars/debian.yml:

```
packages:
  - nmap
```

The output from the ansible-playbook is like the following:

```
PLAY [install nmap] **************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] ***********************************************************************************************
ok: [server@x.x.x.x]
ok: [debian@x.x.x.x]

TASK [debian : include_tasks] ****************************************************************************************
included: /Users/xxxx/ansible/roles/debian/tasks/install_nmap.yml for debian@x.x.x.x, server@x.x.x.x

PLAY RECAP ***********************************************************************************************************
debian@x.x.x.x       : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
server@x.x.x.x         : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

I tried to change the way i declare the variables in group_vars and hardcode them in the roles, but nothing is working. As it does not show an error, i am not sure where the problem lies.

Comment: The task does not have any tags, so with `--tags nmap` the include runs but the included task does not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that, because of *include_tasks*, the tag *nmap* is not inherited by the tasks in the file *install_nmap.yml*. The tag *nmap* is applied to the task *include_tasks* only. See [Including and Importing](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/user_guide/playbooks_reuse_includes.html#including-and-importing)

```yaml
- include_tasks: install_nmap.yml
  tags: ['nmap']
```

To solve the problem, either import the tasks

```yaml
- import_tasks: install_nmap.yml
  tags: ['nmap']
```

or *apply* the tag to the tasks in the file

```yaml
- include_tasks:
    file: install_nmap.yml
    apply:
      tags: ['nmap']
  tags:
    - always
```

See the [examples](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/include_tasks_module.html#examples).